# Alternative tools to export Oracle database to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, oracle-11g-r2, migration

I've got an Oracle database that I need to export (schema and data) to SQL Server.

I am trying the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle, but it is horribly slow, grossly inefficient and very un-user-friendly, e.g. I was having problems connecting to the SQL Server DB during data migration - but it still spent ~5 minutes preparing all the data before attempting a connection to SQL Server, then when it failed, the 5 minutes of preparatory work were wasted.

Right now, I'm just trying to connect to another Oracle DB using this tool, I left it overnight and came back this morning, and it's **still** stuck on 19% of "Loading objects..."  And this is on a machine with a good 18GB RAM, of which maybe 8.5 GB currently in use.  Task Manager shows me that `SSMAforOracle.exe` is using 0 CPU, 0 PF Delta, and no change whatsoever in memory usage. In other words: frozen stiff. Absolutely intolerable.

Are there any other tools out there that can migrate an Oracle DB to SQL Server a little more efficiently?

Comment: What sort of size and complexity is your source database?

Comment: @Mat - approx 200 working tables, largest table has millions of records

Answer (score 0):

Found [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) - this looks pretty good.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If Navicat does in fact allow exporting an Oracle database to SQL Server, it would help to note the steps required to do so instead of pointing the OP at a management product website.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA - I *am* the OP...